# Make "Suggested edits" review tasks wider

Tags: script, review

### About

Ever since the [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues) suggested edits have been too narrow. Especially when containing code blocks. But it doesn't have to be that way anymore.

#### Screenshots

###### Before

[image] [image]

###### After (One possible setup)

[image] [image]

#### Features

Includes choices to:

- Remove the "Big Box" on the right 1/3 of the screen.
- Replace the radios with real buttons, like they used to be.
- Or keep the radios, but move them to allow for a wider review.
- Rework the title to not repeat information.
- Move the post type (Question / Answer / Tag Wiki) to the title bar.
- Move the post-diff choices (Inline/Side-by-side/Side-by-side Markdown) up next to the Filter-button.
- Add diff-choices on title/tag only edits.
- Move the daily review progress to the "Review task"-button
- Add back the user cards of both the author and previous editor.
- Show the post author as highlighted in the post notice.
- Get the statistics of the editor with a link to their suggested edits.
- Change the size and colour of the edit "comment", which is renamed to "summary".
- Make notifications more prominent.
- Remove the line trough on deleted content.
- Show user filters in compact form.
- Current or Stack Design new user cards and/or Stack Design moderator flair.
- Use Stack Desing post summary that include tags.
- Put a link on all post titles.
- Pick an API threshold before seeing a notice.
- User interface with previews to toggle the options on or off and pick colours/text size.
- Adds a  to Community user by default, removing the trailing "Bot"-box.

#### How it works

Installing it will apply the default settings to reviews in the "Suggested edits" review queue

To change the settings click on this icon on the top right:

[image: settings icon]

and a user interface<sup>1</sup> to change the settings will appear:

[image]

<sub>1 Uses [Stack Design](https://stackoverflow.design/)</sub>

#### Platform

Should work with any user script manager & any browser running JavaScript.
Tested on Windows 10 using:

- Opera & Chrome with [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net).
- Firefox with [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/).

#### Sites

Works on:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)
- [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com)

Adding a header to the script can made it work on any site:

```js
// @include      /^https://<siteurl>/review/suggested-edits.*/
// @exclude      /^https://<siteurl>/review/suggested-edits/(stats|history)/
```

Example for [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com):

```js
// @include      /^https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits.*/
// @exclude      /^https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/(stats|history)/
```

#### Download

[GitHub](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/tree/main/StackReviewSuggestedEditsRework) | [Install](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackReviewSuggestedEditsRework/StackReviewSuggestedEditsRework.user.js) | [Tersed/Minified](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackReviewSuggestedEditsRework/StackReviewSuggestedEditsRework.ters.user.js)

#### Contact

For bugs, please post here. Comments are fine too.

#### Changes

| Version | Updates |
| --- | --- |
| 1.2 | Added option to highlight the post owner in notices |
| 1.1 | Fix of the broken post summary on 23rd of August 2021 |
| 1.0 | Original |

###### Note

The script uses the user script manager's storage to store user settings.

When a new option is introduced, please press the "Restore tab settings" to force the default. Then pick your choices on the tab and save.

Comment: Please note that the post summary of reviews seems to be under construction. Stack is breaking that part of the script in the same rate that I can fix it. So for now, just turn "Using Stack Exchange API" ON in the "Extra" tab in the settings.

Comment: It seems that this has now settled down. I've been using the script with "Using Stack Exchange API" turned OFF since the last update of my script to the repository on September 3rd.